# What does $c_1(a,b)$ mean in the context of a solution to a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

The solution to the PDE $$u=r\cdot\nabla u= x\, \partial_xu + y\,\partial_yu + z\, \partial_zu$$

where $u=u(x,y,z)$ is given by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u(x,y,z)%3Dx*D%5Bu(x,y,z),x%5D%2By*D%5Bu(x,y,z),y%5D%2Bz*D%5Bu(x,y,z),z%5D) as 
$$u(x,y,z)=x\,c_1\!\left(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}\right)$$

How to interpret this notation? I figure $c_1$ is an integration constant, but what about the parenthesis/vector? Is $c_1$ instead some vector function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution, $c_1$ is an arbitrary differentiable function of two variables.  In other words, what WA is saying is that $u(x,y,z)$ depends only on the ratios of the variables $x,y,z$.

For an example, I'll choose a fairly random function of two variables: $c_1(s,t) = \sin(s^2) + t/s$.  Then $x\; c_1(y/x, z/x) = x\sin(y^2/x^2) + xz/y$, which (for $x, y \ne 0$) is a solution of your PDE.

Comment: And the two variables must be of the form $\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}$? Also, why is $c_1$ chosen as the notation here? What is this function typically called?

Comment: There's no particular reason to call it $c_1$.  Presumably, if you had a solution with two arbitrary functions, one would be $c_1$ and the other $c_2$.